# Compare data from two tables

Tags: sql, linux, postgresql, debian

I want to compare the data between two tables (data1 & data2) as the request:

```
SELECT COUNT(email) FROM data2 WHERE data2.email NOT IN (SELECT email FROM data1)
```

But each table are so big, data1 => 25 millions, data2 => 38 millions of tuples.
So this request is awesome for small tables but sooo long for biger like mine...

Is anyone knows another way (faster) to compare data between two tables ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be aware that you count emails repeatedly. If an email is in 100 records in data2 and not in data1, then you count 100, not 1.

To get the query fast, you need an index on both data1.email and data2.email. Then the dbms doesn't actually even have to access the tables; it can work on the indexes only.

To count each email just once you would `COUNT(distinct email)`. But the IN clause is usually slow, as others have mentioned already. You can simply do it thus (provided you *want* to avoid repeated counting):

```
select email from data2
except
select email from data1;
```

Comment: Big thanks Thorsten ! I confirm, EXCEPT is so faster than NOT IN ! :o

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:
- try to use an inner join between table 1 and 2
- try to use WHERE NOT EXISTS instead of NOT IN
- try to create an index on the email columns of both tables which will speed up the comparison of the 2 columns

Johan

Answer (score 0):

If you can, put indexes on both tables' email columns, and then try using an `OUTER JOIN` to find the unmatched entries - this usually gives a fast result than `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
                @Data1  AS Data1
LEFT OUTER JOIN @Data2  AS Data2 on Data1.Email = Data2.Email
WHERE
    Data2.Email IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(email) 
FROM data2 
WHERE not exists 
(select 1 
from data
where data2.email = data.email)
```